# XML XPath 1.0 - How to correctly use 'not' function in XPath expression

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I'd like to return only the AA nodes that don't contain a BB child node.  I'm using XPath 1.0 btw.

Sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<T>
 <AA>
  <ZZ>z</ZZ>        
 </AA>
 <AA>
  <BB>b1</BB>        
 </AA>
 <AA>
  <BB>b2</BB>        
  <CC>c</CC>        
 </AA>
 <AA>
  <CC>c</CC>        
  <DD>d</DD>        
 </AA>
</T>
```

So with the above exampe, only the first and last AA nodes should be returned.
I've tried something like:

//AA/*[not(BB)]/..

...but this still returns all 4 AA nodes.

Is the 'not' function available in 1.0?
If so, what am I doing wrong?  thank you...

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Perl?

Comment: Sorry, out of habit ... only if I included just one 'my' stmt, huh?

Answer (score 2):

Your expression selects nodes that are children of `AA` nodes that do not have `BB` as children. If you make the assertion about the `AA` node then you should get what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => 'test.xml');

my $nodeset = $xp->find('//AA[not(BB)]');

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
  print "FOUND:\n";
  print ' ', $node->toString, "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
FOUND:
 <AA>
  <ZZ>z</ZZ>        
 </AA>
FOUND:
 <AA>
  <CC>c</CC>        
  <DD>d</DD>        
 </AA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that

```
//AA/*[not(BB)]/..
```

is just a short way or writing

```
descendant::AA/child::*[not(child::BB)]/parent::node()
```

As this makes more obvious, `BB` doesn't check if the name of the context node is `BB`, it finds the children named `BB`.

---

You're checking if the child elements of `AA` have child elements `BB`.

You want to check if the `AA` elements have child elements `BB`.

```
//AA[not(BB)]
```

Comment: thank you; yes, that works ... I could of sworn I tried that ... geez!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
//AA[not(BB)]
```

The expression you tried selects the elements contained in `AA` which don't contain `BB`.